# Retrieving nested objects from Json file using Jackson API

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am having a Json file.
It contains Nested objects, I am trying to retrieve nested objects by u

Comment: Your json is invalid..

Comment: do you have a java class with matching fieldnames for jackson to map it to?

Comment: Yes I Do have Java classes?
I am not getting clue how can i retrieve these objects from this file? Problem begins when i reach array of TestCase becauseit it is array of object TestCaseData.

Comment: tell me what is your "trouble"

Comment: Have cleaned up your JSON message, and the problem in your JSON should be obvious with proper indentation

Comment: I am trying something like this to get in form of Objects: ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);TestSuite suite=mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Users\\abhi\\Desktop\\Json\\InTS.json"),TestSuite.class); System.out.println(suite.getTestSuiteInfo().getDescription());

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonschema2pojo for generating Java Classes for your Json and then you can use :

```
String response = "Your full json here";

TestSuiteResponseRO testSuiteRO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, TestSuiteResponseRO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON seems invalid..here is valida JSON..post your code if below JSON does not work..

```
{
"TestSuite": {
"TestSuiteInfo": { "-description": "parse" },
"TestCase": [
{
 "TestCaseData": {
 "-sequence": "sequential",
 "-testNumber": "2",
"-testCaseFile": "testcase\\Web\\Ab.xml"
}
},
{
"TestCaseData": {
"-sequence": "sequential",
 "-testNumber": "3",
"-testCaseFile": "testcase\\Web\\BC.xml"
}
}
]
}
}
```

> 1.I have removed '}' on of line 22..
>
> 2.I have swapped brackets of line 19 and 20..